# What does "All changes saved locally" mean?

Tags: google-docs

I'm using Google Docs. I have downloaded the file as a Word document and now every time I change anything it says `All changes saved locally`.

If I send this document to someone will they see the updated version or do I have to download it again after I make changes?

Answer (score 2):

You have to upload it again. If you download your file it is only stored on your computer and no longer linked to Google Docs as long as you do not upload it again.

Comment: can we access it again after browser closes?